# how can i include a socket.io-client in the service worker of chrome Extension(manifest V3)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, socket.io, service-worker

I copied the client socket.io script from the cdn and then used importScript but when i tru to run it gives

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at JSONPPolling.doPoll (socketio.js:3683)
at JSONPPolling.poll (socketio.js:4369)
at JSONPPolling.doOpen (socketio.js:4313)
at JSONPPolling.open (socketio.js:3399)
at Socket.open (socketio.js:2796)
at new Socket (socketio.js:2725)
at socketio.js:2560
at Manager.open (socketio.js:470)
at new Manager (socketio.js:383)
at lookup (socketio.js:220)
```

How can i solve this, my code for the service worker file is

```
try {
importScripts('socket/socketio.js')


const socket = io("http://localhost:8080")


socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(socket.id)
})


} catch (e) {
console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: socketio uses `document` so you can't use it in a service worker which doesn't have DOM. Find a different library or don't use ManifestV3.

Comment: Did you manage to avoid this issue?

Comment: You can use `jsonp: false`  option  to avoid `document` issue.

Comment: @gaurav_rajput Is the socket connection still alive in manifestv3?

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

For me `{jsonp: false}` did omit the document error, but didn't get connected to my server.

try using `{ transports: ['websocket'] }` as options in socket.io connection

service_worker.js 
`const socket = io('http://localhost:9000', { transports: ['websocket'] });`

In my node server 
`const io = require('socket.io')(server, {cors: '*'})`

This works for me! : )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the webpack to bundle the socket.io client into the background service worker.

To avoid the `document` issue mentioned by [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) you can use `jsonp: false` option.

```
const socket = io('URL', {
  jsonp: false,
});
```

Comment: jsonp is no longer a valid option in socket.io-client v4